# Can sudo to user but 'run command as' is denied?

Tags: sudo, users, solaris, su

I was wondering how to run a command as another user from a script without password.
`sudo -l` return: `(root) NOPASSWD: /bin/su - someuser`

There is no problem to sudo as `someuser`. Command `sudo su - someuser` works without password. 
But every time I try to execute command as this user I'm prompted for password. I tried both: 

`sudo su -c pwd someuser
sudo -u someuser pwd`

Are there any alternatives? What is the cause of the problem? I don't have root access.

Comment: Do you use `sudo su - someuser` as `someuser`? That should prompt for  the `sudo` password, as well as the others. In my computer it does. It's Linux though.

Comment: No, I use this as my own user. There is no question about password.

Comment: I used this as my own user as well. It prompted for the `sudo` password. What do you mean then?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I might be stating the obvious, but I think the answer is in the config.

You've mentioned your config shows

```
 (root) NOPASSWD: /bin/su - someuser
```

So you are permissioned to run only one command ie `/bin/su - someuser` as root (so this avoids su prompting for a password) and the NOPASSWD: means sudo will not ask you for a password to do it.

But you want to run other commands as someuser, (directly from your own shell) `sudo -u someuser somescript` But that's not configured.

You want, `sudo -l` to show something along the lines of

```
(root) NOPASSWD: /bin/su - someuser
(someuser) NOPASSWD: /bin/ls, /usr/bin/whoami, /home/someuser/bin/ascript
```

(above output may not be 100% as it will be displayed but hope you can understand what I mean)

The way you are configured at the moment, means you must first su to someuser and then run commands as that user.

It sounds like you don't have admin control over this machine. Maybe develop the script as the *someuser*, then you'll have a list of commands and a script tested, to got back to your admin, to add to `/etc/sudoers`.

Answer (score 1):

it's possible to remove sudo password prompt for non-root users by adding (or uncommenting existing) line in `/etc/sudoers` file

it's also possible to create separate files for users in `/etc/sudoers.d/` directory

---

adding passwordless sudo users:

`someuser ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: ALL`

the same thing for groups:

`%somegroup ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: ALL`

these lines can be added (appended) to `/etc/sudoers` file, or to separate ascii (text) files in `/etc/suedoers.d/` directory

Comment: Could you show which line in sudoers, and what the file in sudoers.d would look like, to help OP, What do you think is at fault in the original post.

Comment: I think my user exist in the sudoers. `sudo -l` return: `(root) NOPASSWD: /bin/su - someuser`.

Answer (score 1):

This works for me.

```
sudo su - user <<< "command"
```

Answer (score 0):

If command `sudo su - someuser` works without password then you should be able to do this:

```
sudo -u someuser command
```

If that does not work, then it is probably set to only allow `su` command without a password. Thus, try this:

```
sudo su -c "COMMAND1; COMMAND2" -m "USER"
```

e.g.

```
sudo su -c "cd /home/user ; mkdir testdir" -m "user"
```

Comment: It's true. But I tried and did not work.

Comment: see updated answer please

Comment: It prompted for the password.